# MS Access: There isn't enough memory to perform this operation (Reports)

Tags: ms-access, ram

There are some of the posts with the same subject but the behavior I have with my MS Access application (with SQL Server database) is different than others.

On my PC (Win10 Pro, 8GB DDR4 2GB free), and the majority of clients 'PCs, it works perfectly fine. But on two of the clients' machines, **reports** couldn't be open even in **Design mode** (all reports, and just the reports - forms, queries are fine). All of the reports are very simple, with up to one subreport.

So, when the client wants to open a report he received msg box:
*"There isn't enough memory to perform this operation. Close unneeded programs and try the operation again."*

Both of them have enough RAM. The first one has 12GB DDR3 (7,5 GB free), and another one has 8GB DDR3 (3,5 GB free). Both are using Windows 10 Pro and Office 365.

I tried to:

1. Increase Paging File (Virtual Memory)
2. Setting "Graphics performance preference" to "Power saving" for MS Access
3. Disc Clean-Up
4. Reinstall MS Office

Comment: Try [Compact and Repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2) the Access application. Even if the data is stored in a SQL-Server DB, Access keeps temporary data in the front-end. If this does not help, try converting the query to a [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application, an AutoExec macro is responsible for setting application options and initiating the login form. Usually, upon login (considering it uses a SQL Server backend, linking tables/pass-through queries), I would test if the reports were operational after the fact.

For some reason, the problem is consistently repeatable on versions 16501.20196, but doesn't manifest on 16327.XXXXX.

I found a workaround for this issue, here's how you can check if it will work for you: Hold the shift key while opening the file and select a report of your choice to open (you could even create a blank report solely for this testing purpose). Open and close this report prior to logging in or running any code.

Following this procedure, upon login, the reports should function as expected.

As a temporary solution, I've incorporated the open/close report in print preview as the initial action in my AutoExec macro. This seems to alleviate the issue for now, at least until Microsoft addresses the root cause.

Please consider this a workaround rather than a definitive solution.

Comment: Yes, that is what happens now. I made the test on the client's PC, and this is what I got:

Client 1 - OK  - (Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20200) 64-bit 
Client 2 - Not OK - (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 32-bit
Client 2 - Not OK - (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 64-bit 
Client 2 - Not OK - (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 64-bit

Also, when I start it with SHIFT, as you said, at any client with 16501.XXXXX, it works fine. So, definitely, it is about the update.

Comment: We reinstalled Office with Office Deployment Tool at _Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.XXXXX_, and turned off updates. It works fine now.

Comment: You can use this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841).

Answer (score 0):

Did it happen after the Office 365 update 2305?
It happened also to us and with Microsoft we are trying to sort out the reason (that in our case is connected to the update 2305 build 16501.20196).
Also here there is a new post about https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access-blog/access-releases-14-issue-fixes-in-version-2305-released-june-1st/bc-p/3841797

If yes, contact Microsoft through the feedback function inside Access (so maybe with more cases they are able to find what it's in common).